# Is there something that can prevent a browser from downloading a cookie?

Tags: cookies, browser

I know this is a somewhat strange question.

I have a website and many browsers. 
I clear the cache of any browser.
I visit a particular website with each browser.

Only one of the browsers downloads three more cookies, while any other browser doesn't.

What can prevent a browser from installing cookies?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the website itself is simply sending different `Set-Cookie` headers depending on the browser. Use your browser's developer tools and check the network traffic. Look in the response header for each loaded URL and see what cookies are set.

You may also have browser add-ons like adblock preventing certain URLs from loading and setting cookies.

Comment: I've nothing that stops cookie: moreover, it should stop ANY other cookie  :-)   while, I see lots of cookies but some (important) browsers ignore them

Comment: Ok, maybe I should send some feedback to some browser vendor: one of the browsers shows one cookie in the set-cookie string, two cookies in the response tab, no cookie in the storage menu. Stunning!

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are part of the http header. Sites which uses cookies are sending this information inside the header of the http response. So, there is no such thing as a downloaded cookie. The http "page" itself provides the values.

The browser decides if the cookie will be saved and used for each further request to the server.(It's an important function if the server needs to hold a state) Some browsers allow you to deactivate cookie handling, so no cookie will be saved (and no cookie value will be send to the server on further communication).

Comment: Sorry for misusing the word "downloading"